# Integrating Swift iOS App with Rails Web App Using URL Request and CoreData

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, swift, core-data

I'm new to posting to SO. I'm looking for any assistance/feedback/suggestions related to my college capstone project in Computer Science. I'm spent the last few months developing an iOS app to document bird sightings. My last step is to be able to send the user's data to a Rails server and display all the sightings. I'm saving the user's info for each sighting (lot/long, time/date, descriptive factors) using Apple's CoreData API. I then built a quick and dirty rails web app and database. My problem now is that when I try using a POST request to my web app, I get an error saying that it is a bad request. The web app is here: https://apptezt.herokuapp.com/birds

Here is my controller:

```
    class BirdController < ApplicationController

        skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :create

        def index
            @bird = Bird.all
        end
        def new 
            @bird = Bird.new
        end
        def create
            @bird = Bird.new(birdz_params)
            if @bird.save
                redirect_to "/birds#index"
            else
                render "new"
            end
        end

        private
        def birdz_params

            params.permit(:typez, :lat, :long, :singing, :aggressive, :notes)
        end
    end
```

And my route:

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      root to: "bird#index"

      get "/birds" => "bird#index"
      #ROUTE TO POST
      get "birds/new"=> "bird#new"
      post "/birds" =>"bird#create"
    end
```

Here is my Swift code in my app to POST the data:

```
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://apptezt.herokuapp.com/birds")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "type=bird&"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        }
        task.resume()
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post the console output of your request?

Comment: @TimoSchilling It's extremely long but here is the main output:         statusCode should be 200, but is 400
response = Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x60000082df20> { URL: https://apptezt.herokuapp.com/birds } { status code: 400, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 0;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Mon, 28 Nov 2016 03:06:31 GMT";
    Server = "WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.2.4/2015-12-16)";
    Via = "1.1 vegur";
    "X-Request-Id" = "606db502-07e2-46e3-ab84-ee03b0695d75";
    "X-Runtime" = "0.035915";
} })

Comment: That's the Swift App output. But what is the Rails App output? Can you ran the Swift App against a Rails App on your local machine?

Comment: @TimoSchilling Here are the logs for a POST method (I'll try running it locally, any suggestions for that?):                     
2016-11-28T03:06:30.445549+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-11-28 03:06:30] INFO  ruby 2.2.4 (2015-12-16) [x86_64-linux]
2016-11-28T03:06:30.445806+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-11-28 03:06:30] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4 port=23191
2016-11-28T03:06:31.883830+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/birds" host=apptezt.herokuapp.com request_id=606db502-07e2-46e3-ab84-ee03b0695d75 fwd="70.186.104.116" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=40ms status=400 bytes=264

Comment: The heroku logs are only server logs and no application logs, they aren't helpful. Run `rails server` in your Rails App

Comment: @TimoSchilling Sorry for such a delayed response. Basically at this point I have been able to get a local server running and can post results from my app there. However, the Heroku deployed app still does not work. Could it be a security measure by Heroku? Is there an authorization token or something that needs to be passed during the post request? Thank you for all the help.